# Issue with Sentry JDBC Integration and P6Spy Connection URL Approach in Spring Boot Project

Tags: postgresql, sentry, p6spy

**Problem Description:**

I have successfully integrated Sentry JDBC into my Spring Boot project following the documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/performance/instrumentation/jdbc/). To implement the integration, I opted for the "Connection URL way" as outlined in the P6Spy documentation [here](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#connection-url-way) since I am not directly using the Spring Datasource. My project is running on Postgres 15.

However, I encountered an unusual issue where some of my queries are failing with the following error message:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: improper qualified name (too many dotted names): com.p6spy.engine.wrapper.preparedstatementwrapper
  Position: 23
```

Upon further investigation, I identified the exact query causing the problem:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (com.p6spy.engine.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper@7b30fd4a) AS count_query;
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

Here's the relevant code snippet from my project:

```java
private static final String CREATE_PAGINATION = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (%s) AS count_query;";
private static final String PATTERN_TO_REMOVE = "LIMIT\\s+\\d+\\s+OFFSET\\s+\\d+";

public Pagination createPagination(Connection conn, String QUERY, int page, int size) throws SQLException {
    final String COUNT_QUERY = String.format(CREATE_PAGINATION, QUERY.replaceAll(PATTERN_TO_REMOVE, ""));
    try (PreparedStatement countPs = conn.prepareStatement(COUNT_QUERY);
         ResultSet rs = countPs.executeQuery()) {
        rs.next();
        long total = rs.getLong(1);
        return createPagination(page, size, total);
    }
}
```

---

**Request for Assistance:**

I need help resolving this issue. It seems that the generated query includes a reference to the `com.p6spy.engine.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper`, and this is causing problems with the PostgreSQL database. How can I address this error and ensure proper query execution?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I figured, the `toString()` method of `PreparedStatementWrapper` is not returning the query as it does with `PreparedStatement`, causing the above issue.